# How to change all route(url) with ending / in Apache Server's .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to change my website's all route(url) with ending / in .htaccess file.
i.e:

```
http://example.com => http://example.com/
http://example.com/1/id=1 => http://example.com/1/id=1/
http://example.com/pages/mgmg => http://example.com/pages/mgmg/
```

Pls, I have a little exp in Apache's .htaccess, teach me...

Comment: There is so much knowledge here on SO already, if you want to learn, try to make use of it!  Search, search, search before posting a question.

Comment: NB: Your first example is the same URL. There is _always_ a slash at the start of the URL-path (after the hostname), even though this might not be displayed in the browser.

Comment: Do you have an existing `.htaccess` file? Have you tried anything? Presumably you are already correctly linking internally to the canonical URL _with_ a trailing slash?